# Is there any difference between bool, Boolean, and BOOL in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I know BOOL is actually a typedef of signed char, but what about Boolean?

What is the difference between bool, Boolean and BOOL?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have a type called "Boolean" or "bool", can you clarify your question?

Comment: I don't know, Boolean appears in CF library...

Comment: Sure it does. It is C so it has those too. And C++ stuff.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`Boolean` is an old Carbon keyword (historic Mac type), defined as an `unsigned char`. `BOOL` is an Objective-C type defined as `signed char`. `bool` is a defined version of the `_Bool` standard C type. It's defined as an `int`. Use `BOOL`.

Edit (2019): Apple talks about the underlying implementation of `BOOL` in some [new documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/bool). Basically, on macOS, `BOOL` is still ultimately a `signed char`, but on iOS and related platforms, it a native C `bool` underneath.

Comment: `Boolean` is used in CoreFoundation (which Carbon is mostly built on top of now), so while you should use BOOL in objective-C, when dealing with any CoreFoundation APIs, Boolean is still in use.

Comment: Oh, I see, so I should use BOOL for common use and Boolean in CF. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, you're right. CoreFoundation does define a version of `Boolean`, but that's separate from Carbon's definition. See MacOSTypes.h vs. OSTypes.h. And on 64-bit systems that don't use C99, CoreFoundation's `Boolean` is an `unsigned char`.

Comment: From objc.h:
`// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.` So BOOL for Objective-C, Boolean for everything else.

Comment: If `stdbool.h` is included in C99, then `bool` is a macro expanding to `_Bool`, which is a built-in true Boolean type representing either 0 or 1, it is not an `int`.

Comment: Nowadays, one should always use `bool` (including `stdbool.h` if not coding in [Objective] C++) except to interoperate with existing APIs that use one of the older types.  Using a real Boolean type (can only take the values 0 and 1, any nonzero integer converts to `true` automagically) obliterates an entire class of possible bugs.

Comment: Zack, this also introduces a class of bugs called pointer to bool conversions. Still prefer bool over BOOL though.

Comment: @zwol is right. `BOOL v = 2; NSLog(@"%d", v);` outputs "1", not "2". Reference to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/bool?language=objc)

Comment: It seems BOOL is a C99 bool on arm64 macos (Apple Silicon) as well. So maybe it has more to do with the chip architecture and less to do with the operating system? Here's a link to a GH issue investigation https://github.com/SSheldon/rust-objc/issues/110

Answer (score 9):

I don't want to take away from @JonShier's useful answer, but I've more to add than fits well in a comment...

#### `bool`

Introduced to standard C in the C99 spec. (The C99 standard was *published* in 1999, but it took some years after that to become widespread in use.) Prior to that, "plain" C had no built-in Boolean type, so libraries that built on top of C often defined their own. (And often continued using their own types for source/binary compatibility even after they embraced C99 compilers.)

Use this if you're writing ISO C and aren't working in the context of higher level libraries with their own Boolean types.

#### `Boolean`

Defined by Carbon (the early-OSX-days compatibility bridge from the even older Mac Toolbox), which you might still see in some projects (due to transitive `#include` of headers that are really only around for compatibility with really old source code).

Don't use this.

#### `BOOL`

Defined by ObjC because NeXTSTEP needed its own Boolean type back in 1988. (The oldest `objc.h` I can find on my office bookshelf dates to 1992 and includes a definition of `BOOL`.)

ObjC `BOOL` has often been defined as `typedef signed char`, meaning that it can hold more values than just `YES` (1) and `NO` (0). [That can be a problem if you aren't careful](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/). (Why even do that? Because if a type is one bit wide, it's hard to pack into well-aligned memory for good performance.)

However, in iOS 64-bit (including tvOS) and watchOS, the compiler defines `OBJC_BOOL_IS_BOOL`, which makes ObjC `BOOL` just an alias for C99 `bool`. That means the language/compiler ensures that nonzero values are always stored as 1, so you don't have the issues that come from `typedef signed char BOOL`. (Still gotta worry about them on macOS or 32-bit iOS, though.)

#### TLDR

If you're working in ObjC with ObjC frameworks (like Cocoa, UIKit, etc), you should use `BOOL` for consistency with the APIs you're interacting with. (Besides, `YES` and `NO` are much louder than `true` and `false`, and it's good to be emphatic when you're talking about absolute truth, right?)

Answer (score -1):

If your new APIs have no need to interact with old ones, `bool` is more specific and clear than BOOL.

When building an non-Mac application with Xcode 9, `BOOL v = 2; NSLog(@"%d", v);` outputs "1", not "2".

Reference to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/bool?language=objc)