# bool versus BOOL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool)
>   [Is there any difference between BOOL and Boolean in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016846/is-there-any-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-in-objective-c)

I noticed from the autocomplete in XCode that there is a bool and a BOOL in Objective-C. Are these different? Why are there two different kinds of bool?

Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 10):

Yes they are different.

- **C++** has `bool`, and it is a true Boolean type. It is guaranteed to be 0 or 1 within integer context.
- **C99** has `_Bool` as  a true Boolean type, and if `<stdbool.h>` is included, then `bool` becomes a preprocessor macro for `_Bool` (this header also defines `true` and `false` as preprocessor macros for `1` and `0` respectively).
- **Cocoa** has `BOOL` as a type, but it is just a typedef for `signed char`. It can represent more values than just 0 or 1.
- **Carbon** has `Boolean` as a type, but it is just a typedef for `unsigned char`. Like, Cocoa's `BOOL` it can represent more values than just 0 or 1.

For Cocoa and Carbon's “Boolean” types, they should be thought of as zero meaning false, and any non-zero value meaning true.

Answer (score 3):

`BOOL` is defined in Objective-C as `typedef signed char BOOL`, while `bool` is the datatype defined in C99.

Comment: `bool` is also defined in C99 in stdbool.h.

Comment: @Chuck: You are, indeed, correct. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: bool is #def to _Bool which is the actual c99 type.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `bool` unless you need to interoperate with code that uses `BOOL`, because `bool` is a real Boolean type and `BOOL` isn't.  What do I mean "real Boolean type"?  I mean that code like this does what you expect it to:

```
#define FLAG_A 0x00000001
#define FLAG_B 0x00000002
...
#define FLAG_F 0x00000020
struct S
{
    // ...
    unsigned int flags;
};

void doSomething(S* sList, bool withF)
{
    for (S* s = sList; s; s = s->next)
    {
        if ((bool)(s->flags & FLAG_F) != withF)
            continue;
        // actually do something
    }
}
```

because `(bool)(s->flags & FLAG_F)` can be relied upon to evaluate to either 0 or 1.  If that were a `BOOL` instead of a `bool` in the cast, it *wouldn't* work, because `withF` evaluates to 0 or 1, and `(BOOL)(s->flags & FLAG_F)` evaluates to 0 or the numeric value of FLAG_F, which in this case is *not* 1.

This example is contrived, yeah, but real bugs of this type can and do happen all too often in old code that doesn't use the C99/C++ genuine boolean types.

Comment: For Objective-C, this is not good advice and is not the convention.

Comment: If the convention is to use the more error-prone programming style, then the convention is wrong IMO.

Comment: chpwn: I don't see how conforming to the convention conflicts with the advice in the answer; he says “unless you need to interoperate with code that uses `BOOL`”, and all Cocoa code is such code. ☺ Moreover, if you read his demonstration, `bool` does look really handy.

Comment: What would be wrong with `if((s->flags & FLAG_F) && !withF)`? I agree overall that a proper boolean type should be used in favour of an integer type.

Comment: That doesn't do quite the same thing!  The correct version of my code, if BOOL were in use, would be `if(!!(s->flags & FLAG_F) != !!withF)`.  But the larger point is, yes, you *can* always fix the code at the point where the bug is, but if you use a proper boolean type you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

BOOL is actually a signed char (thanks Yuji), while `bool` is a true boolean from the  ISO C99 standard.

See here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/of-bool-and-yes.html

Comment: Strange, in Windows, `BOOL` is actually an `int`!

Comment: In C++, `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are all different. So, in Objective-C++, `BOOL` is not a `char`; it's a `signed char`.

Comment: You're right - I'll edit my answer since I see it's grammatically incorrect anyway.